# I can't adjust brightness on my Lenovo g50-80

Tags: windows-8.1, display, brightness

My Lenovo g50-80 laptop showed blue screen and it restarted saying "your pc ran into problem". After that restart, the brightness is 100% and it can't be adjusted. I have tried updating Microsoft basic display adapter, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your device manager? It sounds like you have not got the correct drivers installed.

Answer (score 0):

Look under the Power Settings.  It may coincide with your Power Plan, so that might have to be adjusted to get the setting you want.  I know the link is for brighter, but you should also be able to make it dimmer. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-make-the-display-on-my-laptop-brighter